# How to export to excel sap.m.Table

Tags: javascript, excel, export, sapui5, export-to-excel

How to export to excel sap.m.Table when the table is bound with two different models ?

This is an example of my table:

```
<Table id="gEmployeesTable">
            <headerToolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar>
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <OverflowToolbarMenuButton icon="sap-icon://excel-attachment" useDefaultActionOnly="true" defaultAction="onExportButtonPress">
                        <menu>
                            <Menu>
                                <MenuItem text="Export" />
                                <MenuItem text="Export As..." />
                            </Menu>
                        </menu>
                    </OverflowToolbarMenuButton>
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column id="firstColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>textOne}" />
                    <footer>
                        <Text text="{footerModel>/footerPropsOne}"/>
                    </footer>
                </Column>
                <Column id="secondColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>textTwo}" />
                    <footer>
                        <Text text="{footerModel>/footerPropsTwo}}"/>
                    </footer>
                </Column>
                <Column id="thirdColumn">
                    <Text text="{i18n>textThree}" />
                    <footer>
                        <Text text="{footerModel>/footerPropsThree}"/>
                    </footer>
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem id="gEmployeesListItem">
                    <cells>
                        <Link text="{columnModel>/propsOne}" />
                        <Text text="{columnModel>/propsTwo}" />
                        <Text text="{columnModel>/propsThree}" />
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

and this is an example of my controller

```
createColumnExportConfig() {
        const aCols = [
          {
            label: "One",
            property: "propsOne",
            type: this.EdmType.String,
          },
          {
            label: "Two",
            property: "propsTwo",
            type: this.EdmType.String,
          },
          {
            label: "Three",
            property: "propsThree",
            type: this.EdmType.String
          }
        ]
  
        return aCols
      },
  
      onExportButtonPress() {
            const oTable = this.getTable()
            const oRowBinding = oTable.getBinding('items')
  
            const oSettings = {
                  workbook: {
                      columns: this.createColumnExportConfig(),
                      hierarchyLevel: 'Level'
                  },
                  dataSource: oRowBinding,
                  fileName: 'EmployeesTable.xlsx',
                  worker: false 
            };
  
            const oSheet = new Spreadsheet(oSettings)
            oSheet.build().finally(function() {
                  oSheet.destroy()
            })
      }
```

So far there is no problem with showing the data from the columns in an excel document, but I still have no imagination what should I do to show the data from the footers because it's an another data source (another model) and how can I combine all the data to show it in the document in the same order as it is shown in the table.

What I wanted is the excel document which is identical to my table structure.
My question is how can I develop it?

As an example I used following source:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet/sample/sap.ui.export.sample.formatting/code